# Python, Selenium, and Beautiful Soup for URL

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a script using Selenium to access pastebin do a search and print out in text the URL results.  I need the visible URL results and nothing else.

```
<div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-visibleUrl gs-visibleUrl-long" dir="ltr" style="word-break:break-all;">pastebin.com/VYQTSbzY</div>
```

Current script is:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.pastebin.com')

search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print link.get('href',None),link.get_text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need `BeautifulSoup`. `selenium` itself is very powerful at locating element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.pastebin.com')

search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# wait for results to appear
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.gsc-resultsbox-visible")))

# grab results
for link in results.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.gs-title"):
    print link.get_attribute("href")

browser.close()
```

Prints:

```
http://pastebin.com/VYQTSbzY
http://pastebin.com/VYQTSbzY
http://pastebin.com/VAAQCjkj
...
http://pastebin.com/fVUejyRK
http://pastebin.com/fVUejyRK
```

Note the use of an [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html) which helps to wait for the search results to appear.

Comment: Alecxe thank you very much that is what I needed now to play more Selenium is awesome.  Again Thanks

Comment: As I am new to both python and selenium would it be possible for the results to print as follows.

Califonia Online traffic school test answers – pastebin.com
Pastebin.com/vyqtsby

Hiiiii chem. 4 – pastebin.com
Pastebin.com/VAAQCjkj

Thanks

Comment: If for any reason it were still wanted to use bs4 to parse, it could be done like this: `html = result.get_attribute('outerHTML')`, where `result` should contain all relevant html to be parsed. Then bs4 could be used normally: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`