# BeautifulSoup: get information from website (parent/child issue?)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am new at web crawling and I am encountering an issue.

I want to get 2 informations, from this page:
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/197070/massive-darkness

The informations I want are:

> - minimum number of players
> - maximum number of players

I have done a rignt clic on "1-6 players" go to "inspect" and I get:

```
<div class="gameplay-item-primary">                     <!----><span ng-if="::geekitemctrl.geekitem.data.item.minplayers > 0 || geekitemctrl.geekitem.data.item.maxplayers > 0" min="::geekitemctrl.geekitem.data.item.minplayers" max="::geekitemctrl.geekitem.data.item.maxplayers">     <!----><span ng-if="min > 0">1</span><!----><!----><span ng-if="max>0 &amp;&amp; min != max"><!----><span ng-if="min>0">–</span><!---->6</span><!----> </span><!---->                    Players                 </div>
```

I tried:

```
url=requests.get('https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/197070/massive-darkness')
website=url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(website, "html.parser")
tmp=soup.find("div",{"class":"gameplay-item-primary"})
```

but type of tmp is None (instead of class 'bs4.element.Tag') --> there is no information in it and I don't know why....

> Question1: How do I get the 2 informations I want?
>
> Question2: What does "!----" means?
>
> Question3: When I only do `soup.find("div")` I get a class 'bs4.element.Tag' object but I still don't know where to get my information with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as we've figured out that required page use dynamic js generated content, solution will be more difficult, but we don't need to change a lot.
Now we need to install selenium webdriver and selenium server to your computer. Use this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) and [this](https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5) (in case you'd like to proceed procedure on server).
But as for now just type in your console:
`pip3 install selenium chromedriver`
Now we have to run chromedriver in console.

simply type `chromedriver`

Than your whole script should look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib3
import certifi
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


class Scrapper:
    def __init__(self):
      self.http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
      #below we define our chrome driver.
      self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
      self.options.add_argument('headless')
      self.options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
      self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=self.options)

    def page_process(self, url):
      self.driver.get(url)
      self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
      return self.driver.page_source

    def parse_element(self, element):
      return bs(element, 'html.parser')

class Job(Scrapper):
  def __init__(self):
     super().__init__()

  def parse_process(self, url):
      source_page = super().page_process(url)
      parsed_page = super().parse_element(source_page)

      divs_on_page = parsed_page.find_all("div",{"class":"gameplay-item-primary"})
      your_div = divs_on_page[0]
      your_text = your_div.get_text()
      players_arr = your_text.split('-')
      min_players = players_arr[0]
      max_players = players_arr[1]



 url = "https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/197070/massive-darkness"
 b = Job()
 b.parse_process(url)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I did use BeautifulSoup4 but I do not use urllib3.....

I try your code even I do not undertsand it (I am a newbe). But I don't have "Scrapper", "pip install Scrapper" bug and "conda install Scrapper" doesn't find it..... So I am stuck :-)

I wil try to re-ask my question in a simple way. Thank you anyway! :-)

Comment: Hi Grynets, I don't understand your question.... What should be correct? Moreover I work on your code. Scrapper did not exist but scraper did.... So I install it and correct your code. However I still get some error: "TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)". I work on python3 maybe that's why....

Comment: by the way I tried to apply your code using:

`parse_process(self, 'https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/197070/massive-darkness/marketplace/geekmarket')`

Maybe it is not the right way

Comment: `Scrapper` it's custom class which you create in first block of code. You don't need to install anything.

Comment: That is what I understand in the first place but after running the first cell containing your first code. I tried to run the second cell containing your second code but I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Scrapper'`... :-(

Comment: Have you moved Scrapper class to another file? Have you ever used OOP? If don't, you can do everything in one file. In this case you don't need to `from Scrapper import Scrapper`. Just unite all code in one file, remove Scrapper class and rewrite methods in one class. Remove inheritance from Scraper class and run your code. If you don't understand clearly what I mean, I can rewrite my first answer to procedural code (in one file with one class)

Comment: Hi @Grynets. I copy your first code in an ipython notebook that I saved in Anaconda3/Lib/site-package with the name "scrapper". Then I run your second code but I still get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Scrapper'".... Do you know what I did wrong? I don't know what OOP is... If you can rewrite your answer that would be great because I do not understand everything I have to do....

Comment: @Anneso I've rewritten it, please check.

Comment: thank you so much for your time! However it is still not working.... Did you try it on your computer? I get this error: "TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".... But I don't know why because when I read your code I do not see 2 argument when you call __init__....

Comment: I think I understand why it does not work. Job took "a" as an argument. So init get 2 argument : "self " and "a". I correct the init function in the job class to add one argument. It is working for this line. However I still get an error at the next line: "first_page is not define". I tried to change first_page into source_page but it does not work either...

Comment: I add "print(divs_on_page)" and I get an empty list..... I think the error might be the same than in my first program. Maybe it is more of an html understanding probleme....

Comment: @Anneso my bad.Thanks for your attention :) I've edited code, please try again

Comment: I still get the error "TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".

Comment: I correct the __init__ function in Job(Scrapper) with "def __init__(scrapper,self):"

Comment: @Anneso does `parsed_page` contain something?

Comment: @Anneso I've got it. If you make `print` on `parsed_page` you see something like this: `GEEK.geekitemPreload = {"item":{"itemdata":[{"datatype":"geekitem_fielddata","fieldname":"name","title":"Primary Name","primaryname":true,`. Problem is that page DOM generates from javascript. That means that you need to use selenium webdriver to parse this page. Selenium can emulate browser behavior.

Comment: @Anneso I can write solution for this task, but later, I think in 6-7 hours. As for now I'd recommend you to watch this videos and try to implement behavior by yourself. You need pyqt4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfV1MIRBOcqClP6VZXsvyZS&index=4 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tS7E05Cfik. Or read this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31864214/6066986 https://coderwall.com/p/vivfza/fetch-dynamic-web-pages-with-selenium

Comment: Thank you! I will look at it tomorrow :-)

Comment: @Anneso, please check answer.

Comment: yeeeeessssssss it works!!!! Thank you very much. I was fighting with the installation of PyQt4 but you did it with selenium ;-). Jus a little error the symbol '-' is not really a 'six underscore', so the split did not work. I copy paste it and it works. Thank you again!!!! :-)

Comment: @Anneso your welcome :) If you don't mind, and my answer is correct, please set it as correct :)